# Objective C if statement not working

Tags: iphone, c

I have been trying to find out the problem to this for a day now, and can't seem to find the fix.

```
int person;



-(IBAction)personOne:(id)sender{
[twoPerson stopAnimating];
[fourPerson stopAnimating];
[threePerson stopAnimating];
[onePerson startAnimating];

person = 1;

}

-(IBAction)personTwo:(id)sender{
[threePerson stopAnimating];
[fourPerson stopAnimating];
[onePerson startAnimating];
[twoPerson startAnimating]; 

person = 2;
}
-(IBAction)personThree:(id)sender{
[fourPerson stopAnimating];
[onePerson startAnimating];
[twoPerson startAnimating];
[threePerson startAnimating];

person = 3;
}
-(IBAction)personFour:(id)sender{
[onePerson startAnimating];
[twoPerson startAnimating];
[threePerson startAnimating];
[fourPerson startAnimating];

person = 4;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is if this button is clicked then Person is equal to an integer value.

I don't see a problem with this code at all.

I then have another button that's using if statements.

```
-(IBAction)go:(id)sender{
ammountDueFloat = ([ammountDue.text floatValue]);
tipPercent1;
findAmmount = tipPercent1 * ammountDueFloat;
NSString *showAmmountText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", findAmmount];
showammount.text = showAmmountText;



if (person = 1) {
    showPerPerson = findAmmount / 1;
    perPersonLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"$%.2f",       showPerPerson];
}
if (person = 2) {
    showPerPerson = findAmmount / 2;
    perPersonLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", showPerPerson];
}
if (person = 3) {
    showPerPerson = findAmmount / 3;
    perPersonLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", showPerPerson];
}
if (person = 4) {
    showPerPerson = findAmmount / 4;
    perPersonLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", showPerPerson];
}
else {
    showPerPerson = findAmmount / 1;
    perPersonLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", showPerPerson];
}

}
```

Whenever I click the button 'go' it always assumes the value of person is the last if statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: Xcode4 gives you a warning when you use '=' operator in a if() condition. You should heed the warnings.

Comment: You should use equality operator(==), no the assignment operator(=), for comparisons.

Comment: Go and take some classes in C...You are assigning the value where you want to compare!!

Comment: I think that if statement is unnecessary. You can just set `showPerPerson = findAmmount / person;` for cases where person = [1...4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use == to compare

```
if(person == 1)
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
person = 1
```

It assigns 1 to person, rather than checking whether the person is equal to one. As 1 is assigned to person, this condition is always true. You need `==` operator instead of `=` in `if` conditions.

```
if (person == 1) {

} else if (person == 2) {

} // similar
```

Answer (score 2):

**I would write it as comment, but it's not convenient, so it's here**

As both answers suggested, you should use equality operator, please consider:

```
if ( (person < 1) || (person > 4 ) {
    person = 1;
}
showPerPerson = findAmmount / person;
perPersonLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"$%.2f",       showPerPerson];
```

instead of the whole if cases.

And if you use the if cases, you should add else after each case, otherwise the last part will be run every time person != 4:

```
if (person == 1) {
//..
}
else if (person == 2) {
//..
}
else if (person == 3) {
//..
}
//..
```